# TIN file not creating

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, 3d-analyst, tin

I want to create the DEM by using the contour lines but I am unable to do so. Following the 3D analyst tool > Data Management Tool> Create TIN. Then I added contour line (shape file) as an input file and filled the necessary column but it doesn't create any TIN. As I go for closing the file it gives warning of result is running in background.

Comment: Since the ArcGIS Desktop default is to run geoprocessing tasks in the background (asynchronously), a more accurate title to this question would be "TIN file not created yet" or "TIN file would have created if I hadn't terminated the task". If you want to wait on the TIN creation, uncheck the background processing property in the Geoprocessing Options menu (this can only be changed when no processes are currently backgrounded).